# top not working in batch mode: 'dumb': unknown terminal type

Tags: terminal, top

I can't get top (`top: procps version 3.2.8`) to run in batch mode.

```
root@zenitel063a52:~ top -b
'dumb': unknown terminal type.
```

It will run normally in interactive mode (just when calling `top`).

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/304470/problems-with-cron-script-and-term-definition-using-top-command

Comment: @rahul It is similar, however i feel that the question is more stripped and is more of a  generic Linux (can be applied to embedded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `dumb` terminal is missing in `/usr/share/terminfo/d/`.
A workaround is to copy a different terminal and rename it to dumb.

```
cd /usr/share/terminfo
mkdir d      #if directory not there
cp v/vt100 d/dumb
```

The reason why this hack should work is because `dumb` terminal should only provide support for the simplest functionality, and other terminal provide that.

Comment: ...which seems to be what @rahul was suggesting